# round down 2 decimals php

Tags: php

i am trying to round down for example this number 1.01 to 1.00 - 1.09 to 1.10 - 1.11 to 1.10 etc

so i tried this

```
echo round(1.01); //return 1
echo round(1.01, 2);   //return 1.01
```

but this is not returning 2 decimals, i need to get 1.00

want to round to 1 decimal and display 2 decimals

Comment: **Not working** Not a helpful description of whatever is or is not happening

Comment: Seems to work for me exactly as [the manual page say it will](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) Please be more specific about what you think it shoudl be doing that it is not

Comment: Looks like you want to round to 1 decimal and display 2 decimals.

Comment: what function would do that ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to round to 1 decimal and then print two decimals.

You can use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to print the two decimals:

```
echo number_format(round(1.01, 1), 2)."\n";
echo number_format(round(1.09, 1), 2)."\n";
echo number_format(round(1.11, 1), 2)."\n";
```

This outputs:

```
1.00
1.10
1.10
```

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a number. `1` is identical to `1.00`, mathematically. If you want to show it with two decimals, that's a presentational issue, not a mathematical one, and as such it's not the job of the `round` function (or the code which PHP uses by default to display numbers when you echo them) to provide that.

However there is another PHP function [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) which, as the name suggests, allows you to format numbers for display. The second parameter you pass to it allows you to set the number of decimal places to display.

This:

```
$number = round(1.01);
echo number_format($number, 2);
```

should satisfy your requirement.